# Get File name from JFileChooser without loading to memory

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a JPanel with three JButtons that open a JFileChooser.
When I select each file, I just want to get the file path, so I can later open to a File f1, f2, f3 one after the other but not all together (i.e. close one open the next one). 
Is there a way to get the file name without calling getSelectedFile()?
This is killing my program and it just freezes...

Thanks

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openActiveSKUsButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(UI.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File file = fc.getSelectedFile(); // this is bad
            ActiveSKUsFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            //This is where a real application would open the file.
            log.append("Active SKUs file selected is: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            file = null; //doesn't seem to work
            System.gc(); //ditto as above

        } else {
            //log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
        log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

    } 
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  `getSelectedFile()` returns a `File` object, which is just an abstract representation of the file that does not attempt to access the file until you call a method on it.  Just instantiating a `File` should not hang.  How are you detecting the "freeze" and how do you know it is at this point?  Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger?

Comment: You should not be invoking `System.gc()`. Java will determine when to do garbage collection. Also variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most are correct but not all. Be consistent!!!

Comment: It's likely the call to `System.gc()` that is causing the long delay.  As @camickr points out, remove that line - you shouldn't be invoking it pretty much ever.

Comment: Instead use: `ActiveSKUsFilePath = fc.getSelectedFile();` and `log.append("Active SKUs file selected is: " + fc.getSelectedFile().getName() + "." + newline);`. **Get rid off:** `File file = fc.getSelectedFile();`, `file = null;` and `System.gc();`.

Comment: Make use of the File reference over the string representation, it’s generally easier and more widely accepted through out the api

Answer (score 0):

Store the `File` reference in an instance variable and use it later. This means opening the file is to be triggered by another action.

```
public class MyGuiApp {

    private File file1;
    private File file2;

    ...

    // Action listener for file chooser
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ...
        file1 = fc.getSelectedFile();
        log.append("Active SKUs file selected is: " + file1.getName());
    }

    // Action listener for opening the file - like pressing a button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // use or open file 1
    }
}
```